# How to display synchronised videos/presentations across multiple displays?

Tags: video, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, microsoft-powerpoint

The company I work for are planning an exhibition stand for a trade show. We'd like to display 4 separate (but identical length) videos or presentations across 4 displays (likely to be 37" HD TVs) which will be scattered around the exhibition stand.

The videos/presentations will each have different content, but will have common title slides/company logos at the same point in time (beginning, middle and end). We'd like to synchronise the playback such that the the titles/logos appear on all the displays simultaneously.

What would we require in terms of hardware/software to drive this from a single "standard" laptop computer?

(The content has yet to be produced, so we're flexible on format eg video or PowerPoint presentation, etc)

Comment: Both hardware and software recommendations are off-topic on [su].

Comment: Welcome to Super User! You are asking an off-topic question. Please read [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic), [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: Check http://officeone.mvps.org/ -- they may have something that'll help with this.